# Graph API: Search Facebook Post with location param

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API to search facebook POST with location parameter. I am using the below code.

```
string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={0}&type=post&limit=10&location=Newark,NJ,US", txtSearch.Text);
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string xml = web.DownloadString(url);
```

The above code works fine witout any error, but it doesnt look like it is considereing location parameter.

Is it possible to add any location paramter to the search query fetching Facebook Post? 
location parameter can be in form of actual location string (e.g. Los Angeles, CA,US) or GeoCode value ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not support location por "post" search using API

Answer (score -2):

You can't do it for post but you can search a place by location with a geocode:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=...`

Comment: You can do that on type=place, not for type=post